# Need to draw a Workflow activity chart

Tags: javascript, .net, graph, charts, workflow

I need an open source graph for below requirement.

I have 10 steps in my custom .net implemented workflow application. A “document” goes through this workflow forward and backward against time.
I want to plot the “document” activity in the workflow like below.

x axis – from left to right - pre-defined workflow steps
y axis – from top to bottom  - time 
a line with an arrow head should represent a movement from one step to another step.
This arrow head could point to the next step or previous step as the document can traverse both ways. It could happen even in the same day. So I guess we will need some curved arrow lines.

I need a good open source graph (may be javascript) or a simple mechanism to draw above chart. I tried the Gantt chart but really it doesn’t exactly behaves the way I want. It has time for the x axis and really focus on the duration for a particular movement not the activity.

Appreciate your help.